# java.exe uses too much CPU and crashes

Tags: java, multithreading, server, crash, cpu

- Windows Server 2008 R2

  - WebSphere
  - Java 6

**Issue**
* Currently there are **two java.exe processes** constantly running on this box. 
* One of them has **upwards of 180 threads** with a couple in particular consuming **40-60%+**
* Each of these threads(*there are heaps*) are named (**msvcrt.dll!endthread+084**)

**What I've tried**
* Upon reducing priority of both of these java processes and killing their process tree's it has reduced the CPU usage almost completely. 
* I have also tried searching for any updates to drivers, checking logs, process investigation, but everything else seems fine.

**Temporary Solution**
* This will only be a temporary fix as the box restarts daily and will revert back to normal priority boosting that CPU usage back.

**Why this is an issue**
* On a rare occasion which seems to happen more frequently, I would say once or twice each month, the box crashes and I believe it's because it's CPU usage spikes to over 100% for extended period of time, not sure what causes it, maybe too many threads, I'm not sure I'm not well versed in computers.

Comment: You need to find out why your application is using so much memory.  It most likely due to a bug (e.g. a memory leak) in the application running in WebSphere.  If you are not a programmer, you could start by talking to the people  who supplied you with the application.

Comment: Great, thank-you! I will have a look and if I get any results will post back here with updates.

Comment: I checked the java.exe threads and msvcrt.dll!endthread+0x84 there are over 180 of these same threads, however there are a couple and 1 in particular that bounces from 0.01 to 86%+ CPU usage, any ideas?

Comment: Have you talked to the people who supplied you with the application yet?